# How to allow an application in AppArmor?

Tags: debian, apparmor

I am using `redshift`, which has support for custom shell scripts in hooks when certain events happen. However, these hooks are not executed because of AppArmor:

```
[11541.395814] audit: type=1400 audit(1696093800.648:39): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="/usr/bin/redshift" name="/home/philipp/.config/redshift/hooks/test-hook" pid=15384 comm="redshift" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

How can I make this work? I searched online, but did not find a satisfying, simple solution.

I am only using AppArmor because it is installed by default in Debian. If the best solution is to uninstall it, that’s fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is described in the Debian Handbook, 14.4.3. The command `aa-genprof` walks you through the required steps.